# Using Typescript & Playwright, check if an argument passed is in an enum

Tags: typescript, enums, argv

Basically, I'm passing arguments by way of the package.json scripts and want to see if the passed argument is in an enum and grab the first one that appears.  This is running in a playwright, but that shouldn't impact anything since I'm evaluating these arguments prior entering the Playwright test function.  The problem is, I'm new to typescript and I'm getting an error that I can't figure out.

Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node test Boston"
```

enum.ts:

```
export enum testDataCities {
    boston = `boston`,
    burbank = `burbank`,
    peoria = `peoria`,
    provo = `provo`
}
```

test file:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test'
import { testDataCities } from './enum'

let city = process.argv.filter(arg => arg in testDataCities)
```

So when I run this, foobar ends up being an empty array.  Also, VS Code is giving a nice little squiggle and error under testDataCities to the tune of:

```
'const' enums can only be used in property or index access expressions or the right hand side of an import declaration or export assignment or type query.
```

this has me dumbfounded.  Why isn't this working and how can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm stupid and figured it out.
(a) I was using "Boston" not "boston" in the script
(b) I removed the "const" key work in the enum declaraition

Comment: Nicely done. Glad you were able to figure this out, and thanks for posting the solution. It is helpful to those of us who are new to typescript.
Not sure if this is considered best practice for Typescript or not, but this is the reason that I always put enums in all caps, i.e. BOSTON = 'Boston', BURBANK = 'Burbank', PROVO = 'You must be from Utah, because the rest of the world has never heard of Provo.'